# How to shuffle videos with specifics videos in between

Tags: video, media-player, shuffle

I have nearly 1000 video songs and i want to shuffle them and add specific video (Like Ads) in between them. So when i play videos with shuffle, after every 2-3 songs Ad video will be played.

Is it possible with any software? I am using windows 7.